# Sublime Text 3 side bar is not updating or refreshing

Tags: directory, sftp, sidebar, sublimetext3

For some reason the side bar on Sublime Text 3 is just displaying the folder named **Template**. The strange thing is that this folder is already deleted and regardless of that, the folder **Template** should not be displayed when I open Sublime in for example my Dropbox folder. No matter where in Ubuntu I open Sublime *(from command line or Dash)* it will open with that folder named **Template** in the sidebar. **Template** will have the arrow next to it indicating I can expand its contents or hide them. When I press it I see the arrow go from the right to to down position no folder contents show, nothing happens.

Also nothing happens when I go **Project > Refresh Folders**.

This problem happened around the time I was trying to add a new server using SFTP. Not certain if that had anything to do with it.

Any ideas whats happening here?

Comment: Is it a top level folder? If so, it is still being displayed because it is an entry in your sublime-project file.

Comment: @skuroda thanks and how do you get it functioning as one would expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is a top level folder, you need to edit the project itself. You may right click on the folder in the side bar, and select "Remove from Project". Alternatively, you can edit the file itself by going to `Project -> Edit Project`. The top level folders are defined as a list of objects. Remove the entry you want from there, and it will no longer appear in the sidebar. You can write a plugin to clean up a project for you if you find yourself removing items frequently.